# How to optimize and vectorize my function?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

How should I optimize this function for speed? I know I should probably declare the arr before the loop so Python doesn't need to check the if/else condition every loop.

But what else can I do? I know there probably is a way to use map or vectorize the operation.

```
def get_features(images):
    arr = None
    for i in range(len(images)):
        img = X_train[i]
        a, b, c, d = get_rgb_mean(img), get_rgb_std(img), get_hist(img), get_lbp(img)
        j = np.concatenate((a, b, c, d))
        if arr is None:
            arr = j
        else:
            arr = np.concatenate((arr, j), axis=1)
    arr = StandardScaler().fit_transform(arr)
    return arr.T
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question better suited for code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are right! Didn't know such thing existed

Comment: Even there, you should clearly describe what the input is and what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: Will do! Should I delete this question?

Comment: In the overall timing, that `if` test is a minor time consumer.  `np.concatenate` in a loop is poor idea.  Repeatedly I have to tell people, use list append instead.

Comment: `numpy` "vectorization" means applying compiled methods to whole arrays.  With unspecified functions like `get_rbg_mean` that may be impossible.  If you are stuck with calling those once for each `img`, there isn't much you can do to speed this code.  It's not the iteration code that's slow, it's calling those functions many times.

Answer (score 0):

Little optimization:

```
def get_features(images):
    for img in x_train:
        a, b, c, d = (get_rgb_mean(img),
                      get_rgb_std(img),
                      get_hist(img),
                      get_lbp(img))
        j = np.concatenate((a, b, c, d,))
        if arr:
            arr = np.concatenate((arr, j), axis=1)
            continue
        arr = j
    arr = standardscaler().fit_transform(arr)
    return arr.t
```

Note that this works only if x_train has the lenght of image